# Speed of objects in libGDX

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

What is the correct way to move objects in-game with the given speed in libGDX? Eg. I have a circle at the bottom of the screen and I want to move it to the top with speed 10 pixels per second. All phones have different speeds so delta time of render function on every phone is different so how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by this:

> All phones have different speeds so delta time of render function on every phone is different...

But I think your understanding of *delta* value in rendering process is incorrect.
As you probably know already, the *render* method is called multiple times per second, and after every finished call to *render* method the screen is updated. How many times the render method is called can be found by checking `Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()`. So what is the purpose of *delta* value, exactly? *delta* is simply the time span between the current frame (this render call) and the last frame (render call just before the current one) in seconds.

From physics we know that `distance = velocity * time`.

So, to move object by the distance of 10 units per 1 second (unit can be pixels, meters, etc... -- this actually depends on your camera and world rendering logic), we have to compute correct traveled distance for current frame. We know the velocity and the elapsed time (*delta*). We can compute next position like this

```
public void render(float delta) {
    float velocity = 10.0f; // actually 10.0units / 1s
    position = position + velocity * delta; // position can be circle.y to travel up
}
```

Comment: I probably didn't precise my question well. By delta, I meant time between one render function to next render function. And by phone speed I mean... hmm... Eg. one phone can generate 2 FPS so if I want object 10 pixels per second I have to move object 5 pixels in each frame. But if another phone has 10 FPS I have to move object 1 pixel per frame. And I didn't know how to how to measure FPS but I found function Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(). So I can move my object +=velocity*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime().

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delta time with the **libGDX** method:

```
world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

At the end of the `render()` method. This allows to **libGDX** manage the **FPS**.

To adapt the objects speed as you like you can user the Pixel Per Meter Factor: http://seanballais.github.io/blog/box2d-and-the-pixel-per-meter-ratio/